# django template fetch ID or Name for selected dropdown value

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am building a new order form and there are few dropdowns on my HTML page. I would like to build a number based on the dropdown selection. Below is the select tag code which displays the values from the database.

```
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="fit" id="test" data-header="Choose Cost Type Description" title="Choose Cost Type Description">
        {% for row in odrrows %}
          <option name="costtypedesc" value = "{{ row.odr_cost}}">{{ row.odr_cost_desc}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <select>
</div>
```

Is there a way fetch row.odr_cost value to same page instead of row.odr_cost_desc that too without submit? I know we can fetch the row.odr_cost_desc value using javascript but not sure about row.odr_cost.

Here is the sample table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EelIo.jpg)

My dropdown displays drinks, liquids and XYZ. When users selects drinks, I would like to display number 52 in the same webpage(maybe with p tag) instead of drinks.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Fetch it where? What do you want to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your comment. I have added an example. Hope that explains.

Comment: You will need some kind of Javascript for that.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out. Maybe load the JSON file in javascript and fetch the ID.